# Pi 4 Will Not Boot with Noobs or Raspbian

Tags: wifi, boot, boot-issues, pi-4

I recently bought a Raspberry Pi 4, 4GB model, and I cannot get it to boot Noobs or Raspbian. When I purchased it, I knew I wanted to use it for a ubuntu distro, and it booted noobs, but I couldn't find a ubuntu distro through noobs. So I decided to take the card out and reformat it and flash an iso on there.

That was 20 hours ago. Now, I cannot get it to boot either noobs nor Raspbian, even though that the green light shows that it's reading the card. During that time, I was only able to get Ubuntu 19.10 for Raspberry Pi (which is a server implementation), however there was no way to access the internet (both ethernet and wifi), and therefore I couldn't install the desktop version of ubuntu.

Comment: Flash Raspbian to the SD card.  Does that work?

Comment: Please follow the [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151)